# Incorrect values are being assigned - C

Tags: c, for-loop, int, assign

This question was kind of hard to look for in the website. I tried but came back empty handed, so I'm sorry if a similar question has been asked before.

Essentially, I have a piece of code with two for loops. I believe its purpose is unnecessary for the question I'm asking. Anyway, the second time this function is called in my code (it works fine the first time) **the values assigned to variables x and y are incorrect**.

```
void draw_sprite(Sprite *sp){

 printf("outside cicle\nx: %d\ny: %d\n", (sp->x), (sp->y));

 int y;
 int x;

 int p = 0;
 for(y = sp->y; y < (sp->y + sp->height); y++){
   for(x = sp->x; x < (sp->x + sp->width); x++){
     printf("inside cicle\nx: %d\ny: %d\n", x, y);
     vg_paint_pixel(x, y, sp->map[p]);
     p++;
   }
 }

 return;
}
```

The program prints out:

```
outside cicle
x: 34
y: 30
inside cicle
x: 0
y: 136663040
```

As you see, before assigned, the values are 34 and 30 for x and y respectively. But after assigning them, the variables x and y become 0 and 136663040. Thanks in advance.

Definition of sp:

```
typedef struct {
  int x,y;             
  int width, height;   
  int xspeed, yspeed;  
  char *map;           
} Sprite;
```

This function's parameter (draw_sprite) is a sprite created the following way:

```
Sprite *sp;

sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, 0, 0);
```

These values are given through the terminal and I'm using an xpm map that works unless I have to move the sprite. Values xi and yi were both 30. Here is the function create_sprite:

```
Sprite * create_sprite(xpm_map_t xpm, int x, int y, int xspeed, int yspeed){

  Sprite *sp = (Sprite *) malloc ( sizeof(Sprite));

  if(sp == NULL){
    return NULL;
  }

  xpm_image_t img;

  sp->map = (char*)xpm_load(xpm, XPM_INDEXED, &img);

  if(sp->map == NULL){
    free(sp);
    return NULL;
  }

  sp->width = img.width;
  sp->height = img.height;
  sp->x = x;
  sp->y = y;
  sp->xspeed = xspeed;
  sp->yspeed = yspeed;

  return sp;
}
```

Also, as used to compile and generate said error:

```
int(video_test_move)(xpm_map_t xpm, uint16_t xi, uint16_t yi, uint16_t xf, uint16_t yf,
                     int16_t speed) {

  Sprite *sp;

  sp = create_sprite(xpm, xi, yi, 0, 0);

  if (sp == NULL) {
    printf("Error creating sprite.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  sp->xspeed = speed;

  draw_sprite(sp);

  if (speed > 0) {

            while(sp->x != xf || sp->y != yf)){
              destroy_sprite(sp);
              sp->x += sp->xspeed;
              sp->y += sp->yspeed;
              draw_sprite(sp);
            }      

  }

return 0;
}
```

Finally, for the code to work, there's also destroy_sprite:

```
void destroy_sprite(Sprite *sp){
  if(sp == NULL){
    return;
  } 

  if(sp->map){
    free(sp->map);
  }

  free(sp);
  sp = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that shows the definition of sp? Without knowing what type or value `sp->width` and `sp->height` have, this is a bit difficult to help debug. As it is this isn't a minimum working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but if you could also show the specific parameters you're calling `draw_sprite` with that demonstrate the error at hand, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, thank you and sorry for not having included that in the first place.

Comment: NoHoly, understanding what parts of code @kopecs is asking for is very simple: does the attached code compile? No. So add the minimum code to make it compile, with a basic main to showing which `Sprite` struct values make the issue occur.

Comment: @NoHoly based on what you've posted so far, I would conjecture that your error is a result of the values you have in `sp->height` and `sp->width` (and thus, by proxy) `img` not being what you expect, but I can't confirm this. If you could just, in essence, hard code a struct for us with values (not the expected ones, but actually the observed ones) that would be great. You can observe the values either through a debugger (like `gdb`) or just by printing them out.

Comment: @NoHoly if you could just print out the values of `sp->width` and `sp->height` at the top of `draw_sprite` that would be very helpful. As it is, I can't help you further without the source of `xpm_load`, `vg_paint_pixel`, and whatever files you're reading in (or; in the, presumably easier, alternative: those two fields on `sp`).

Comment: So I call the main function (video_text_move) with an xpm image that has been previously done, xi, yi and yf with the value 30, xf is 100 and speed is 4. Printing out the values shows that the cicle completes the first iteration successfully. sp->width and sp->height print out 32. As the cicle goes, x keeps going up until 61, and everytime it does it goes back to 30 and y is incremented. At one point, both are 61 and the program stops. Once it's called again, the sp->width and sp->height values are again 32, sp->x and sp->y are both 34.

Comment: I printed the values to be sure. But upon assignment, I print local variables x and y and x is 0 and y is 136663040. Hope this helps.

Comment: My guess would be you index off the end of `map`. Can you confirm that you're indexing in-bounds every time? (In the for-loops at issue)

Comment: Yes it was correct. However, just to be sure, I used a pre set value for that parameter so no error should exist coming from there. I just tested a little more and assigning a variable with the value of `sp->x` or `sp->y` is the trigger to changing their value.

Comment: Doing
`printf("outside cicle\nx: %d\ny: %d\n", (sp->x), (sp->y));

  int x, y;
  int z = sp->x;

  printf("outside cicle\nspx: %d\nspy: %d\nz: %d\n", (sp->x), (sp->y), z);`
prints out:
`outside cicle
x: 34
y: 30
outside cicle
spx: 0
spy: 136663040
z: 0`

Comment: Solved... since I was destroying the sprite the whole thing didn't know where to get its values from. I mean, the sprite literally ceased to exist at that point. I just created a function to paint the whole screen black instead. It's working now. Thank you @kopecs and sorry for the inconvinience.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments the specific issue sounded like it was in

```c
while(sp->x != xf || sp->y != yf)){
    destroy_sprite(sp);
    sp->x += sp->xspeed;
    sp->y += sp->yspeed;
    draw_sprite(sp);
}
```

Namely the fact that you ran into undefined behaviour as a result of using `sp` after `free`ing it. This caused (in your case) you to read garbage values resulting in an unexpected amount of iteration in your for loops.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a bunch!